# Syntax highlighting in consecutive single-line comments

Tags: syntax-highlighting, include

I'd like to have rich syntax highlighting (using, say, markdown syntax) inside (single-line) comments (as is done in Rust). For now, I'm using the following code, which is not satisfactory.

```
syn include @markdown syntax/markdown.vim
syn region Comment start="///" end="$" contains=@markdown
```

It does handle syntax such as the following.

```
/// Comment with **bold** inside.
```

The first problem is that some markdown syntax (e.g., headings) match the beginning of line, so I would need to match markdown syntax after having removed the comment mark `///` (and a single following space). Otherwise, comments such as the following are not highlighted as desired.

```
/// # Markdown heading (i.e., HTML h1)
```

Second, markdown syntax may span multiple lines, as in the case of titles. And separate comments lead to the contents being parsed separately.

```
This is a title
===============
```

Is there a simple way to do what I want?